# Can someone explain why my Color Space options are different from any tutorial or documentation I've seen?

Tags: shaders, normal-map

I'm wondering if anyone can explain what I'm seeing when I use the "Color Space" drop down on a Image_Texture node? No tutorial or documentation seems to have any info on this. I'm just trying to set it to Non-Color since I'm baking a Normal Map. Hopefully I'm just dumb and missed something obvious, but this has really got me stumped.

[image]

Comment: What filetype is the image you are using (jpg, png, tiff, etc...)?

Comment: I'm using a PNG.

Comment: What Blender version are you using ? Do you work on Windows / MacOS / Linux ?

Comment: Those are definitely non-standard color space options, and I have no clue where they're coming from. Are you using any special add-ons, perhaps related to color management or cinematic style renderings? By any chance, were your textures made using Vray (possibly on a mac)?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm pretty new to blender, I've just been trying to follow some tutorials and have only been messing around with modelling. I'm using Windows, and I don't think I've added much in the way of add-ons. The image/texture I got just by using "New Image" in the Image Editor window.

I tried creating a new project and had the same results. I believe I'm using the latest version of Blender. I might try to reinstall at some point if I can't find a solution.

Comment: If you click the Blender icon at the top left (assuming it is there; this depends on version as well, I believe) and then click "Splash Screen", what version of Blender is indicated?

Comment: Ah, that's how you see that! Looks like I'm using 2.91.0

Comment: Hm -- I can't reproduce the problem in that version of Blender either. Is the image you're using something you could upload as an attachment to your BSE post (just to, also, rule that out as the cause)?

Comment: It's too large of a file (6.05m). It's a 4096x4096 PNG made in Blender. I've tried using other images, also created in Blender. If you happen to have the link to a image file you know works, I could try it?

Comment: You can have custom color profiles. They're in <blender install location>/2.91/datafiles/colormanagement. Not sure how you would have got them if you installed Blender regularly though.

Comment: Just nuked everything in that folder and I'm still seeing it. :(

Comment: You can try restoring factory settings, go to File > Default > Load factory Settings. Beware though that it will overwrite your settings / preferences. Also make sure you download blender from the official site : https://www.blender.org/download/ Latest stable version is 2.92.0

Comment: just deleted 2.91 and downloaded the new version from the website. to my surprise its still occurring...

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one.  I just spent some time trying a number of color spaces trying to reproduce this, with no luck. What app was the PNG exported from? Does it have an unusual color space of any kind?  Also, do you have any node or shader add-ons loaded into Blender?

Comment: Thanks for trying to reproduce. I didn't export it externally. I just used the Image Editor in Blender and hit New Image, and saved it. I checked the file type and it was PNG. I haven't added any add-ons.

Comment: If you load a PNG image from the web, what happens? You mention wanting a link to a file that works, but in my experience every file works.  I've loaded stuff I've rendered from ZBrush, stuff from Affinity Photo, my editor of choice, and images from the web.  I've never had an external image not lead correctly. I've also baked normal maps and occlusion maps using Cycles in Blender and they worked fine. So if your experience isn't that most images work, you may have some kind of corruption or installation problem.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too. I've tried some other images and projects, it occurs no matter what. At this point I'm just going to assume its a corruption. I'll reinstall when I have the time. This wasn't urgent, I'm just trying to learn a bunch of stuff at the same time to get an idea for what blender can do. Thanks for checking this out for me though, its good to know this is a weird issue and not just something I didn't know since I'm a noob.